# How can I reduce the error in my trained values while implementing Artificial Neural Network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

The problem is that I'm getting an error of almost 0.8-1.0 in my trained value which is not acceptable. How do I figure out a way to reduce that error? I've tried reducing the training rate but it didn't work. I'm currently training my system using a dataset in an excel sheet.
Here is the link to the sample data set that I'm using :
http://www.mediafire.com/download/j9o676nvqr32fnb/dataset1.xlsx
Here is the code that I'm using :

```
import numpy as np
import xlrd
def nonlin(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return x*(1-x)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
addr="/home/shashwat08/pycodes/ann/dataset1.xlsx"
wb=xlrd.open_workbook(addr)
sheet=wb.sheet_by_index(0)

output=[[sheet.cell_value(r,1) for r in range(sheet.nrows)]]  #output array
mv=[[sheet.cell_value(r,0) for r in range(sheet.nrows)]]    #input array

output=np.array(output)
mv=np.array(mv)

op=output.ravel()
ip=mv.ravel()

np.random.seed(1)

syn0=2*np.random.random((1,4))-1
syn1=2*np.random.random((4,1))-1

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    for j in xrange(100000):
        l0=ip[i]
        l1=nonlin(np.dot(l0,syn0))
        l2=nonlin(np.dot(l1,syn1))

        l2_err=op[i]-l2

        if(j%10000)==0:
            print("Error "+ str(np.mean(np.abs(l2_err))))
        l2_delta=l2_err*nonlin(l2,deriv=True)               #delta value
        l1_err=l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)
        l1_delta=l1_err*nonlin(l1,deriv=True)

        #syn1=syn1+l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
        #syn0=syn0+l0.T.dot(l1_delta)
        L1=l1.T
        L0=l0.T

        syn1=syn1+0.2*L1*l2_delta
        syn0=syn0+0.2*L0*l1_delta

print("Trained values\n")
print l2
```

## Your help will be appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An artificial neural network accepts a set of hyperparameters that decides the accuracy of classification of your test dataset given that your neural network has been trained on a training dataset.

**These hyperparameters are:**

**1. Learning rate (most commonly represented by the symbol alpha)**

**2. Number of epochs (One epoch is the training of weights and biases by iterating over the training dataset atleast once).**

**3. Mini batch size (If you are using a Stochastic Gradient Descent method with back propagation with training, then the size of the mini batch plays a huge role in deciding the accuracy of classification of the neural network).**

**4. The accuracy with which your training dataset is annotated.**

And I don't think you have included the implementation of an Artificial Neural Network. If you are relatively new to this field, you can take a look at Artificial Neural Network from [this](https://github.com/skymanaditya1/Automating_Dataset_Generation) repository.

An Artificial Neural Network has been implemented from scratch for the problem of sound event detection and classification.